# Forcing Intel NIC 82599 to 1Gbps

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, network-adapter

I am trying to force the 82599 link to 1000Mbps and FD.

I am running Windows 10.

When trying to configure the adapter settings for the Ethernet device, modifying the link speed is grayed out and set to 10Gbps.

This is over an SFP+ connection.

I am struggling to track down why this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

With an SFP+ transceiver fitted most NICs can only run at 10G. For 1G you'd need a 1000BASE-SX or -LX transceiver (if the slot's compatible). Fiber is different from twisted pair.

Forcing a NIC to a certain speed usually works only for 10 and 100 Mbit/s since gigabit requires auto negotiation. (Some ports support "auto-1000" which only negotiates for gigabit and nothing else.)

Additionally, setting full duplex manually requires you to set the switch port the same way. If you can't do that you'll get a duplex mismatch.

Comment: I have a x-520 SFP+ in Windows 7 that I can adjust the settings on. I have not deep dived on differences.

Comment: Yes, on *some* NICs you can select the speed but not on all. The manual should provide details.